# What is the best way to switch a UITableView from list to grouped?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a requirement where I initially have a list of messages only ordered by date/time.  The requirement if for the user to be able to click on a UISegmentedControl (list of 4 buttons) and be able to change the UITableView from a straight list to a grouped list (ie. grouped by category of message).

From what I've read, once the style is set on a UITableView you can not change it.  So what is the best approach to satisfy this requirement?  Kill the view and re-create with the appropriate style?

Not that it makes a huge difference, I am using Xamarin Studio and C#, targeting Mono 3.2.1 and iOS 6+

Comment: I am going to try just creating a grouped UITableView and have ALL messages under one group and hide that group header.  I think that's a bit of a hack, so I'm still open to any better approaches.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than killing the view and re-instantiating, just maintain references to two `UITableView`s, one of each of the appropriate types. Toggle between them using your `Controller` class. The following simple example puts the toggling button in the same `UIView` as the table, which is probably not appropriate, but otherwise shows the technique:

```
public class ChangeableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public bool Grouped { get; set; }

    public override int NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        if(Grouped)
        {
            return 4;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Default");
        if(cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, "Default");
        }
        cell.TextLabel.Text = String.Format("IndexPath {0} {1}", indexPath.Section, indexPath.Row);
        return cell;
    }
}

public class ToggleTableView : UIView
{
    UITableView ungroupedView;
    UITableView groupedView;
    ChangeableSource changeableSource;

    public void SetStyle(bool grouped)
    {
        changeableSource.Grouped = grouped;
        if(changeableSource.Grouped)
        {
            ungroupedView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            AddSubview(groupedView);
        }
        else
        {
            groupedView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            AddSubview(ungroupedView);
        }
    }

    public bool GetStyle()
    {
        return changeableSource.Grouped;
    }

    public ToggleTableView()
    {
        var btn = new UIButton(new RectangleF(10, 10, 150, 40));
        btn.SetTitle("Change", UIControlState.Normal);
        btn.TouchUpInside += (s,e) => ToggleStyle(this, new EventArgs());

        var tvFrame = new RectangleF(0, 60, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - 60);
        ungroupedView = new UITableView(tvFrame, UITableViewStyle.Plain);
        groupedView = new UITableView(tvFrame, UITableViewStyle.Grouped);
        AddSubview(btn);
        AddSubview(ungroupedView);

        changeableSource = new ChangeableSource();
        changeableSource.Grouped = false;
        ungroupedView.Source = changeableSource;
        groupedView.Source = changeableSource;
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ToggleStyle = delegate {};
}

public class TogglingTableController : UIViewController
{
    public TogglingTableController() : base ()
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var view = new ToggleTableView();
        view.ToggleStyle += (s,e) => 
        {
            view.SetStyle(! view.GetStyle());
        };

        this.View = view;
    }
}

[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public  class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    UIWindow window;
    TogglingTableController viewController;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        viewController = new TogglingTableController();
        window.RootViewController = viewController;

        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}

public class Application
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer, I already started heading that direction (with a few differences) but I like what you've done.  I will try this and report back.  Thanks!